# Elevating a variable scope without knowing its name

Tags: tcl, upvar

I need to 'upvar' variables from a `source`'d file (and I don't know their names)

Let's say I have a TCL file containing:

```
set v 7
```

Now this:

```
proc p {} {
  source t.tcl
}

p

puts $v
# => can't read "v": no such variable
```

The file t.tcl must not be changed.

I also can't have knowledge about the content of `t.tcl`. Let's assume it's passed as an `env` variable. How do I make `v` visible at the top level?

Answer (score 3):

For the code you posted, change the definition of `p` to:

```
proc p {} {
    upvar 1 v v
    source t.tcl
}
```

or (to specifically connect the variable to the top level:

```
proc p {} {
    upvar #0 v v
    source t.tcl
}
```

(Note: the syntax highlighter thinks the string `"#0 v v"` is a comment, but it isn't.)

Members of the `env` are global, so you won't have that problem there.

However, if you don't know the names of the variables it's less simple, because you can't `upvar` a variable once it exists.

Is it possible to evaluate the `source` command in the top level, like this:

```
proc p {} {
    uplevel #0 source t.tcl
}
```

(Again, not a comment.)

Or do you have to evaluate it in `p`'s level?

Documentation: [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [source](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/source.htm), [uplevel](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/uplevel.htm), [upvar](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm)

Documentation for [env](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/tclvars.htm)

(Note: the 'Hoodiecrow' mentioned in the comments is me, I used that nick earlier.)

Comment: Hi Hoodiecrow,Note that I said : The file t.tcl must not be changed. I also can't have knowledge about the content of t.tcl.

Comment: @GertGottschalk: it's possible you didn't read my answer closely. Nothing in my answer suggests or requires changes to t.tcl. I did try to suggest a solution for the case where the variable names are unknown, though it depends on whether it is possible/allowed to evaluate the `source` command in the top level.

Comment: Hi Hoodiecrow. Ah, I see. Yes, the code with uplevel works. (though I changed it to uplevel 1 so that it goes up only the 1 level for the proc. Thanks! That resolves my issue.